# How to customize the y-axis values in Swift Charts?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-charts

I have a simple graph (made using [Swift Charts framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts)) where I am showing the percentage of something over time. The x-axis is the time here and y-axis is the percentage. Ergo, I think if the values in y-axis would be like 25%, 50%, etc., it would make more sense to the user.

How can I customize the y-axis values and add a symbol (in this case a `%`) at the end?

This is the code so far:

```
Chart(data, id: \.date) { datum in
    LineMark(
        x: .value("Date", datum.date, unit: .day),
        y: .value("Done", datum.doneCount * 100 / (datum.doneCount + datum.notDoneCount))
    )
    .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
    .foregroundStyle(Color.orange)
}
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Just add this code block to your Chart

```
.chartYAxis {
   AxisMarks() {
       let value = $0.as(Int.self)!
       AxisValueLabel {
           Text("\(value)%")
       }
   }
}
```

Your Chart will then show 0%, 25%, ... as labels

Comment: This works however the horizontal lines (in the background) disappear if I add this code, any ideas?

Comment: You can add `AxisTick()` and `AxisGridLine()` as shown here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707868

Comment: I'd not multiply the doneCount with 100. Instead you could use the original decimal number and normat the value with NumberFormatter() using numberFormatter.numberStyle = .percent. In this way the formatting would not be hardcoded and for example space between number and % would come from common formatting styles.

Answer (score 1):

In order to format the y-axis marks with "%", you can use the Decimal.FormatStyle.Percent:

```
.chartYAxis {
    AxisMarks(
        format: Decimal.FormatStyle.Percent.percent.scale(1),
        values: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]
    )
}
```

If you want to let the default values show (in the case you don't know if the values will be bounded by 100%), you can leave values empty:

```
.chartYAxis {
   AxisMarks() {
       AxisValueLabel(format: Decimal.FormatStyle.Percent.percent.scale(1))
   }
}
```

These and other scenarios are covered in Apple's article "Customizing axes in Swift Charts": https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/customizing-axes-in-swift-charts